# Enforce hive sql-standard security for Presto according to the user submitting the query

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

In presto I set the `hive.security` property to `sql-standard` but as a result, for any user and any table (no matter the privileges granted from Hive) whenever I try to run a select query I get:

`Query 123456789 failed: Access Denied: Cannot select from table.....`

The same queries run in Beeline return the right results (i.e., according to the grants).

More details about my configuration:

- `hive.metastore.authentication.type` is `NONE`, there is no kerberos in place. For the time being I just want the authorization to follow the privileges granted to the user who submits the query.
- `hive.hdfs.impersonation.enabled` should not make a difference in this case as Presto does not currently support impersonating the end user when accessing the Hive metastore. Indeed, it did not make any difference.
- The Presto version is 0.195, the latest.
- The hive connector has a default configuration, apart from the two properties I listed above.
- I tried granting a select on a table to a specific user. The grant allows that user to query in hive, not in presto.
- I tried connecting to presto both using the Presto cli and using a gui client (i.e., DataGrip) via jdbc.

Please any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which presto version are you using? What is your hive connector configuration? What are the grants in the metastore? How do you connect to Presto?

Comment: Hi @PiotrFindeisen, thanks for you answer. Here are some more details. The Presto version is 0.195, the latest. The hive connector has a default configuration, apart from the two properties I listed above. I tried granting a select on a table to a specific user. The grant allows that user to query in hive, not in presto. I tried connecting to presto both using the Presto cli and using a gui client (i.e., DataGrip) via jdbc.

Comment: Hey @AndreaT.Bonanno, which other `hive-site` and `hiveserver2-site` settings do you have enabled on the cluster? And what are there values?

Comment: i set hive.security=sql-standard. When i select from a table i get "Access Denied: Cannot select from table". If i try a grant statement i get "Access Denied: Cannot grant privilege SELECT on table ". What am i missing to enable grants?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? About to go down this route and would love to avoid the pain.  Does it work?  Also, how is your user logging in to presto itself?

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the exactly the way you d'like to setup your environment, here is how I secured presto & hive with success:

- setup kerberos for hive
- setup a hive connector with kerberos for presto with full grant on all hive tables
- create a presto password plugin with ssl
- create a presto access control that maps user/tables-schema access with jdbc or presto-cli and their login/password.
- create a presto logger plugin that track any bad password attempts.

Then user can access:

- hive, thanks to kerberos security
- presto, thanks to presto ssl/password security

Comment: i set hive.security=sql-standard. When i select from a table i get "Access Denied: Cannot select from table". If i try a grant statement i get "Access Denied: Cannot grant privilege SELECT on table ". What am i missing to enable grants?

Comment: Would be nice to see code here for the plugins or references on how you kerberized things.  Any chance you recorded it on git or a blog?

Comment: well I could create a blog post in the future, however i have switched from presto to hive because presto does not handle hive acid tables, wich is a huge limitation